# Concat string as `"@gmail" to Usernames and ignore some lines

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I have a table Table1 with following fields Username   NumberID   CodeUser Company

`Username   NumberID   CodeUser Company
user1        12453      245     G
user2        25145T         Y
user3        1845Z      /500    G
user4        65421      3452    Y
user5        13254      /076    Y`

I would have a query result which will show lines `user1` and `user4` Meaning to ignore WHERE `CodeUser` is empty or has character starting with `/` BUT also `Username` should have the full address if `Company=G` (that means `user1` should show `user1@gmail.com`)

When I do the query separetely, I have the result, but when I try to combine in ONE query, I have errors.

```
1. SELECT Username, CONCAT( Username, "@gmail.com" ) ,NumberID, CodeUser, Company
FROM `Table1` 
WHERE Company = 'G';


2. SELECT Username,NumberID,CodeUser,Company
FROM Table1
WHERE CodeUser >'' AND CodeUser NOT LIKE '/%'
```

Can you help me combine this in ONE query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought you already had all the answers

```
SELECT Username,
  CASE WHEN Company='G' THEN 
      CONCAT(Username, '@gmail.com') ELSE '' END AS GMail,
  NumberID, CodeUser, Company 
FROM Table1 WHERE CodeUser >'' AND CodeUser NOT LIKE '/%'
```

Comment: Thanks again @Tim3880. It works fine. After the last answer I had to add new column and then had concat problem. Now everything just works fine. Your answer helps me also building more queries.

Comment: Hi Tim3880, Hi, I'm back again. I'm trying to have a way to get rid of certains characters which are part of a field. For Example in table2 where I have in field Username user1@gmail.com, user2@gmail.com etc`, How can I delete @gmail.com and only leave the first part of the username which is user1... Thanks again

Comment: Hi in the meantime got this one which works `UPDATE table2 SET Username = REPLACE(Username, '@gmail.com, ' ');`      Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT (case when company = 'G' then CONCAT(Username, '@gmail.com'
             else UserName
        end) as username,
       NumberID, CodeUser, Company
FROM Table1
WHERE (Company = 'G') or
      (CodeUser > '' AND CodeUser NOT LIKE '/%');
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon for asnwering. It helps.